# Aliasing using for or while loop in .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell, variable, arithmetic

Can I use a `for` or `while` loop when I have similar pattern in the aliases that I put in my .bashrc file? For example, I have:

```
alias c0='ssh computer-1-0'
alias c1='ssh computer-1-1'
alias c2='ssh computer-1-2'
alias c3='ssh computer-1-3'
alias c4='ssh computer-1-4'
```

But I want to do something like

```
i=0
while [ i -le 4 ]
do
alias "c$i"="ssh computer-1-$i"
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

which doesn't work unfortunately. I get an error message: `-bash: [: i: integer expression expected`.

Is there a way to achieve what I desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were *very* close:

```
i=0
while [ $i -le 4 ]; do
  alias "c$i"="ssh computer-1-$i"
  i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Just add a `$` character before `i` inside the while loop.

Comment: Now I relaized it was a stupid mistake and hence a bit silly question. I shall be careful before posting next time.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that `i` is just a one-character string. To access the value of the variable `i`, you need to use the syntax to access the value of a variable: `"$i"`.

```
while [ "$i" -le 4 ]
```

(You can omit the double quotes here, but using them is a good habit to get into.)

Shells have basic arithmetic built in. The `expr` utility is a remnant from the old days when they didn't. You can write

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -le 4 ]
do
  alias "c$i=ssh computer-1-$i"
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Note that you don't need (and shouldn't use) a dollar inside the double parentheses. Inside an arithmetic expression, a variable name expands to the value of the variable.

Bash has a C-like for loop syntax. Since this is your bash startup file, there's no reason not to use bash-specific syntax.

```
for ((i = 0; i <= 4; i++)); do
  alias "c$i=ssh computer-1-$i"
done
```

Comment: I feel ashamed of doing such a stupid mistake. How can I forget `$i`? Anyway, your `for`-loop alternative is something that looks far simplified. Thanks a lot.